# Changing Chrome's text zoom when connected to an external monitor

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, zoom

I have a laptop with a rather small builtin monitor, making it very hard to read stuff unless the [chrome text zoom level](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en) is increased to 125%.

One of the external monitors that I connect the laptop to has a low resolution, so 125% zoom is actually not a good setting for that monitor, and I need to use 100% whenever I'm connected to it.

Is there a chrome setting or extension that switches the zoom level according to the resolution and screen size of the monitor I'm plugged into? I would like to just use 125% zoom whenever I'm not connected to an external monitor, and 100% when I am.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a built-in way to do that. There might be an extension, which would require more research though.

I know that you can create multiple profiles in Chrome, so maybe you could use one profile for when you have two monitors and one profile for when you have a single monitor. You might need to make a second Google account for that though, but you can still log in with your normal accounts for everything else. You might even be able to transfer all your passwords and accounts between profiles which could make things easier.

If any of that works, let me know! Hope this helped!

Comment: Profiles must have separate Google accounts, so if OP is logged in on primary profile (that is, current setup), this won't work well.